# how can i select key that contains 2 value in talbe

Tags: mysql, sql

My table:

```
|id |value|
| 1 |  a  |
| 1 |  b  |
| 1 |  c  |
| 2 |  b  |
| 3 |  a  |
| 3 |  d  |
| 3 |  c  |
```

I want to get result like this:

```
|id |
| 1 |
| 3 |
```

whose id contain `a` and `c` values.  Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation is one simple approach:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
WHERE value IN ('a', 'c')
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(value) <> MAX(value);
```

The HAVING clause asserts that there are two different values present in each matching group after the WHERE clause has filtered off all values other than a and c. If the HAVING clause fails, then it means that both a and c are not present.

Comment: What's the purpose of the last row of code here?

Comment: @MaxStrandberg The `HAVING` clause asserts that there are two different values present in each matching group _after_ the `WHERE` clause has filtered off all values other than `a` and `c`.  If the `HAVING` clause fails, then it means that both `a` and `c` are not present.

Answer (score 0):

Other approach:

```
select id       
from   yourtable    
group by id     
having sum(case when value in('a','c') then 1 else 0 end ) = 2;
```

Comment: Why [try](https://www.inc.com/geoffrey-james/3-words-that-guarantee-failure.html) ?? Did you not CHECK if this result it worth posting ?